# Negative energy density of a blackbody?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

The energy density of a Blackbody in terms of the frequency of its radiation is as follows: $\rho(\nu)d\nu = \frac{8\pi\nu^2}{c^3}\frac{hv}{e^{(h\nu/kT)}-1}d\nu $.

If you want to express the energy density in terms of the wavelength of the BB radiation, we know that $\nu = \frac{c}{\lambda}$ and $d\nu = \frac{-c}{\lambda^2}d\lambda$, so you'd make substitutions and get:

$\rho(\lambda)d\lambda = - \frac{8\pi hc}{\lambda^5}\frac{d\lambda}{e^{(hc/\lambda kT)}-1}d\lambda $.

However, the formula of the energy density in terms of the wavelength is a positive quantity, so I know that the negative sign shouldn't be there. I'm assuming we just take the absolute value, but, what does this negative transformation say about the relationship between the energy densities in these two different forms?

Comment: The sign just indicates the edges of the infinitesimal interval, whether it is from left to right or the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign comes from your expression $d\nu = \frac{-c}{\lambda^2}d\lambda$ and it just means that frequency and wavelength are inversely proportional i.e. if you increase $\lambda$ by $d\lambda$ then the frequency decreases i.e. the change in the frequency $d\nu$ is negative.

If you're calculating the energy density over some range you would normally integrate:

$$ E = \int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2} \rho(\lambda)\,d\lambda $$

where $\lambda_1 \lt \lambda_2$. But if you convert to frequency you'll get:

$$ E = \int_{\nu_1=c/\lambda_1}^{\nu_2=c/\lambda_2} \rho(\nu)\,d\nu $$

where now $\nu_1$ is **greater** than $\nu_2$ i.e. the usual order of the limits is reversed. In practice what we do is swap the limits, i.e. integrate from lower to higher frequency as usual, and that means swapping the sign of $d\nu$ to match.